# Rescaling a view defined in a xib (autoscaling subview w/ unexpected results)

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, autolayout

For simplicity, I laid out a view using Interface Builder.  It is a player status view and is used for all 'x' players that are currently playing.  To accomodate a large number of players, we have chosen to resize and relocate the player view based on the number of players.

For example, if there are only two players, the 2 player views will take up much of the screen.  However, if there are 4, each would only account for approximately 1/4 of the screen.

It seems like with the 'Autoresize subviews' and the various struts, it would be fairly easy to control the view.  However, instead I am finding a lot of unexpected behavior.

Whenever I want to change the view size, I call setFrame.  However, with anything less than the original layout size used in the XIB, the view is not shrunk properly but instead draws at the size of the XIB layout.

Based on how much trouble I am having, I am expecting that I am not doing this in the expected manner.  Could someone please point me in the right direction for the proper method of specifying a view and it's component layout and then resizing it?  (I would rather not use CGAffineTransform...)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the container view does not have autoresizesSubviews set.  (In interface builder it's a checkbox called "Autoresizes Subviews").

Comment: I agree, but that isn't it as it is checked.  Is it valid to set a frame size smaller than the layout in the XIB?

Comment: @MobileVet yes it is valid but you need to state the view as freeform and adjust accordingly

Comment: I have it set as 'freeform' as well.  Can you expand on what you mean by 'adjust accordingly'?  Thanks